# Why does my Keras training not resume properly?

Tags: c#, python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to ensure my training is resumed properly. Training uses `Adam` optimizer from `tf.keras.optimizers`. I do set both TF and NumPy seeds.

```
model.compile(optimizer: new Adam(),
            loss: tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy_fn,
            metrics: metrics);

if (resume)
    model.load_weights(path);

var checkpoints = new ModelCheckpoint(
    ModelDir + "/weights.{epoch:02d}-{auc:.4f}-val{val_auc:.4f}" + ModelExtension,
    save_best_only: false,
    period: 1);
Console.WriteLine($"=========== RUN {Run.ID} ===========");
model.fit_dyn(trainData, trainValues,
    epochs: 36000,
    steps_per_epoch: 1,
    initial_epoch: startingEpoch,
    verbose: 2,
    validation_data: validation,
    validation_steps: validationSampleCount,
    callbacks: new ICallback[]{
        Run.TensorBoard,
        checkpoints,
    });
```

Below is the screenshot of TensorBoard, showing 3 runs - 400 steps red one, 200 steps orange, and 200 steps blue with `resume` set to `true`. As you can see, the traininggoes very differently upon resuming. I checked the training data is the same and in the same order.

[image: resume vs continuous]

What could possibly be wrong? It looks like optimizer state is not being restored properly. I tried both `.h5` and `.ckpt` formats. TF 1.12 GPU

Google Collab notebook, illustrating the problem: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1yb9uK7lQM0M5uuk-hypRUacTFdAIfyGZ

[Another one](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ZRhX4VBEWo4fh4zbXL_p-HDCUGTRelnH), where I actually use `load_model` instead of `model.load_weights`

Answer (score 0):

When you save the weights of a model and load it again, you will lose the optimization state. So if you run it with the loaded model, for very first steps, you might get the different losses values, comparing to continuous running of the model.

I believe the reason why you are experiencing differences in the loss, is because of the fact of re-loading the weights of the model

Comment: There's no difference in the loss at the load time. But how do I preserve optimizer state? Before I switched to optimizer from tf.keras, I used `tf.train.AdamOptimizer`, and that gave me warning regarding its weight not being saved. There's no warning for `Adam` from `tf.keras`

Comment: In the Keras documentation, I see a part saying **Saving/loading whole models (architecture + weights + optimizer state) [...]You can use model.save(filepath) to save a Keras model into a single HDF5[..].**. So that says to me, if you save the model, instead of saving the weights, you should be good to conserve the optimization state as well.

Comment: I am using `ModelCheckpoint`. Should I write a custom callback instead? Sounds weird, that it is not the default behavior, and there's no option.

Comment: Sounds strange to me, in the Keras docs in https://keras.io/callbacks/#modelcheckpoint , I see the save_weights_only=False by default, meaning your checkpoint should save everything of the model (due to the Keras doc: ** if True, then only the model's weights will be saved (model.save_weights(filepath)), else the full model is saved (model.save(filepath)).**). But here you say you are loading the weights from what you have stored as the checkpoint, right?

Comment: correct. Maybe its a bug, and I should make a minimal repro, and report to TF. :/

Comment: I've added a collab notebook to demonstrate the issue. Maybe if load_model would have worked, I would not have this problem. But it fails to recognize `leaky_relu`.

Comment: After removing all non-Keras functions, and being able to use `load_model`, the problem still persists. Reported a bug here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/27049